# Click event for dynamically generated elements on listview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried to apply click event to elements dynamically generated.

This example is work well. http://jsfiddle.net/PzSYM/361/

But my code does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/EurT4/8/

This is same code with above link.

**HTML**

> ```
> <ul id="timer_listview" data-role="listview">
>     <li class="timerList">
>         <button>on</button>
>         <span class='status'>play</span>
>     </li>
>     <li class="timerList">
>         <button>on</button>
>         <span class='status'>play</span>
>     </li>
>     <li class="timerList">
>         <button>on</button>
>         <span class='status'>play</span>
>     </li>
> </ul> </div>
> ```

**JavaScript(Jquery)**

```
var counter = 0;

$('#addButton').click(function () {
    $('#console').text('new line added');
    var text = '<li class="timerList"><button>new' + (++counter) + '</button><span class="status">play</span></li>';
    $('#timer_listview').prepend(text);
    $('#timer_listview').listview("refresh");
});

var play = 'play';
$('.timerList').on('click', 'button', function () {
    $('#console').text('clicked');

    var status = $(this).parent().find('span.status');
    if (status.text() == play) {
        status.text('pause');
        $('#console').text('Status Changed');
    }
});
```

**CSS**

> .status {
>       display: none; }

I got a panic why it does not work. :(
Thank you for reading my question.

p.s Anytime welcome to edit my writing.

---

**UPDATE**
I solved this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/EurT4/10/ .
The point is using closest parent.
Thanks to Milind Anantwar.

Comment: I solved this problem. http://jsfiddle.net/EurT4/10/ .
Thanks to Milind Anantwar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding elements `.timerList` dynamically. You need to use:

```
$('#timer_listview').on('click', '.timerList', function() {
        $('#console').text('clicked');              

var status = $(this).parent().find('span.status');
if (status.text() == play) {     
    status.text('pause');        
    $('#console').text('Status Changed');              
}});
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do I use highest selector when make elements dynamically that have events?

Comment: You should use closest parent that remains static.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function onclickButton(e)
{
   alert(e+"Clicked");
}
</script>
<button onclick="onclickButton(1)">Button1</button>
<button onclick="onclickButton(2)">Button2</button>
<button onclick="onclickButton(3)">Button3</button>
<button onclick="onclickButton(4)">Button4</button>
```

Comment: Mmmm, could you explain your code-only answer a little more?